# normal quantile transformation

Tags: r, quantile

I need to do quantile normalization in R

Input file  just a small subset I have over 5000 values:

```
x <- data.frame(A =c(193973, 185750, 185511,NA), B= c(56433,52298, 53040, NA), C = c(4668, 6074,6246, NA))
```

software I am using is recommending

```
xtransformed = qqnorm(x, plot.it =F)$x
```

I don't understand "$x" here in the end ?

**other question is:**

if input is (which is my actual input

```
x <- data.frame(A =c("A","B","C","D"), B = c("X", "Y", "Z","L"), C=c(193973, 185750, 185511, "NA"), D = c(56433,52298, 53040, "NA"), E = c(4668, 6074,6246, "NA"))
```

and I just select column I want to transform

```
y =x[,3:5]
```

Transformed it with that code and it doesnt work? What is the reason

```
ytransformed <- qqnorm(y, plot.it =F)$y

ytransformed
```

I did that. Now I want to plot and see if it has transformed or not? how can I do that?

Comment: So sets expectations that are a bit higher than the typical chatroom. Please learn to capitalize "I". Correcting 20 instances is a PITA. Also SO deprecates multi-part questions as well as extraneous "thanks in advance" types of closures. You should bve specific about expectations. "Doesn't work" says very little.

Comment: ok thank you will be careful in future

Answer (score 0):

The `preprocessCore` package in Bioconductor has this function. First install & load it:

```
source('http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R')
biocLite('preprocessCore')
library(preprocessCore)
```

Then make a matrix out of your data frame, and `normalize.quantiles`:

```
> x <- data.frame(A =c(193973, 185750, 185511,NA), B= c(56433,52298, 53040, NA), C = c(4668, 6074,6246, NA))
> m <- data.matrix(x,rownames.force=nrow(x))
> normalize.quantiles(m)
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 85550.67 85550.67 80825.67
[2,] 82143.61 80825.67 82143.61
[3,] 80825.67 82143.61 85550.67
[4,]       NA       NA       NA
```

Comment: thank you what about the code used? Can you please help to figure out the problem in this code